# updating datatable from gridview updating event

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a datatable that I am populating with data, however if I want to edit the row I am getting an error

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlLinkButton' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox'.

The code that populates the gridview is

```
public void addTochkout(string type, string no)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["table_chkout"];
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = type;            
            dr[1] = no;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            Session["table_detail"] = dt; //save dt to new session
            gridbind();

        }

public void gridbind()
        {
            //gridview
            if (Session["table_detail"] != null)
            {
                DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["table_detail"];
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    chkoutDetail.DataSource = dt;
                    chkoutDetail.DataBind();
                    string countitems = dt.Rows.Count.ToString();
                    Session["cart_counter"] = countitems;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                chkoutDetail.DataSource = null;
                chkoutDetail.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

Now, when I try and update the gridview I am getting the error above from the line

```
dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["TicketType"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[1].Controls[0])).Text;
```

The entire code block where is erroring is

```
protected void TaskGridView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        //Retrieve the table from the session object.
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["table_detail"];

        //Update the values.
        GridViewRow row = chkoutDetail.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["TicketType"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[1].Controls[0])).Text;
        dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["Price"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[2].Controls[0])).Text;
        //Reset the edit index.
        chkoutDetail.EditIndex = -1;

        //Bind data to the GridView control.
        gridbind();
    }
```

I would be very grateful if you could help me solve this issue.

Simon

Answer (score 1):

Note that when you have the Edit option enabled, the first and second cells of the edit mode of the row in the grid view are linkbuttons(Update and Cancel). So probably you have to change the index while getting the textbox in the row

```
//Cell number 2 for the first textbox. 0 for update link and 1 for cancel link
dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["TicketType"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[2].Controls[0])).Text;
```

Comment: found the answer now,

Answer (score 0):

I had figured out my issue just after posting the, but it wouldn't allow me to answer the question.

heres my solutions

```
 protected void TaskGridView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {

        try 
        {
        //    //Update the values.

            string type = e.NewValues[0].ToString();
            string qty = e.NewValues[1].ToString();

            //Retrieve the table from the session object.
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["table_detail"];

            dt.Rows[e.RowIndex]["TicketType"] = type;
            dt.Rows[e.RowIndex]["TicketNo"] = qty;
            dt.AcceptChanges();

            chkoutDetail.EditIndex = -1;

            //Bind data to the GridView control.
            gridbind();

            int value1 = Convert.ToInt32(ddtickettype.SelectedItem.Value);
            int value2 = Convert.ToInt32(ddTicketno.SelectedItem.Value);
            string tType = ddtickettype.SelectedItem.Text;
            string tNo = ddTicketno.SelectedItem.Text;

            int prevTotal = Convert.ToInt32(lblAmount.Text);
            int total = (value1 * value2) + prevTotal;
            Session["TotalAmount"] = total.ToString();
            if (Session["TotalAmount"] != null)
            {
                lblAmount.Text = Session["TotalAmount"].ToString();
            }


        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```